# Back Button Tint Color

Tags: swift, back-button, uinavigationitem, tintcolor

How can I change the back button of a certain navigation controller. I have tried to use

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.red
}
```

I know that if i use `navigationController` it will change the back button tint color on all of my view controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .red
    }
    
    override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = // original color
    }
}
```